# MySQL collation for Spanish, French, Chinese and Russian

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, collation

I currently have a name field that has Collation of latin1_swedish_ci. I need this field to also accept characters in Russian and Chinese. I tried to change the collation of the field in phpMyAdmin to utf8_unicode_ci but it throws an error when trying to convert an existing record with the é character.

Which collation should I set?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` return? You may be running a very old version of MySQL Server that doesn't support the character conversion.

Comment: 5.6.49-cll-lve .

Comment: I tested with 5.7, but I did `ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` and it worked fine. I don't have 5.6 installed anymore because [it's almost at its end of life](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql).

Comment: 5.5 and 5.6 may have problems with index sizes with utf8mb4.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes